# Null check before using variable in function

Tags: kotlin

I am wondering if there is a better way of null checking and assigning value like in this example

```
val result: Clazz? = if (variable == null) null else someFun(variable)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`variable?.let(::someFun)`

You can use the [Kotlin scope function let](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#let) .

> let is often used for executing a code block only with non-null values. To perform actions on a non-null object, use the safe call operator ?. on it and call let with the actions in its lambda.

So in this case `someFun` is only called if variable is not null. Otherwise null is returned.

The longer form of this would be:

`variable?.let { someFun(it) }`

where `it` is the non-null value of `variable`. However:

> If the code block contains a single function with it as an argument, you can use the method reference (::) instead of the lambda:

So we can shorten it to the

`variable?.let(::someFun)`
form